# using checkboxes and counting them in Lightswitch HTML

Tags: javascript, checkbox, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am currently using this code to display checkboxes as a custom control, and it works perfect:

```
// Create the checkbox and add it to the DOM.
    var checkbox = $("<input type='checkbox'/>")
            .css({
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                margin: "10px"
            })
            .appendTo($(element));

    // Determine if the change was initiated by the user.
    var changingValue = false;

    checkbox.change(function () {
        changingValue = true;
        contentItem.value = checkbox[0].checked;
        changingValue = false;
    });
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (newValue) {
        if (!changingValue) {
            checkbox[0].checked = newValue;
        }
    });
```

however now I want to extend this a little, and I am wondering if anyone knows how I can count values based on whether they are true or false.

**What im looking for:**
I have 2 checkboxes below, the *1st* is "**TRUE**" and the *2nd* is "**FALSE**"

- I want to be able to count up these values using something like var count then put it in a while loop, or an array and then display it back on a button like the following for testing purposes: `window.alert("add in text here" + add_code_here)`

[image]

so **example data** would be:

```
var trueCount = 0;
var falseCount = 0;

window.alert("There are: " + trueCount + " values that are true and " + falseCount + " that are false");
```

and the above example `trueCount = 1` and `falseCount = 1`

Thanks for any input people can give me, it is most appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with the custom control check boxes but for the standard switches this code worked for me:

```
var trueCount = 0;
var falseCount = 0;
```

> myapp.TableName.ColumnName_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
>       // count the true or false values
>       contentItem.dataBind("value", function (newValue) {
>
> ```
>     if (contentItem.value == true) {
>         trueCount ++;
>         falseCount--;
>
>
>     } else if (contentItem.value == false) {
>         falseCount++;
>         trueCount--;
>     }
>
>
> });
>
> //count 3 sets both trueCount and falseCount to 0 as they would already be affected by the 
> //post render method. This works by adding or subtracting the amount of false values non 
> //screen (works my my scenario)
> var count3 = 0;
>
> if (contentItem.value == false) {
>     count3++;
> }
> falseCount = falseCount - count3;
> trueCount = trueCount + count3;
> ```
>
> };

```
myapp.TableName.Save_execute = function (screen) {
  window.alert("True Count: " + trueCount + " | falseCount: " + falseCount);

 //set both count values back to 0 for when the screen is next run
 trueCount = 0;
 falseCount = 0;
}
```